# Unable to modify IList object's members

Tags: c#, ilist

I have created an IList variable as below:

```
IList<vertex> matrix = new List<vertex> ();
```

Here, vertex is a structure I defined with one of the members being visited (boolean).

But, when I try to modify this member by traversing through the list as below:

```
matrix[j].visited = false;
```

It gives an error saying "Cannot modify return value because it is not a variable". Any idea why?

Comment: `vertex` is a struct. change it to `class`. If you want mutable data structure don't use struct

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I didn't know that. Thanks for that gem of info.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: That's quite possibly not the right approach though. A vertex type may well be better off as an immutable value type.

Comment: @JonSkeet but.. OP wants to mutate :)

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: The OP wants the *effect* of a mutation. That doesn't mean the type has to be mutable...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you fetch the `vertex` using the `IList<T>` indexer, that will return a *copy* of the value. Changing that copy wouldn't change the list - so the compiler stops you from writing incorrect code.

Options:

- Make `vertex` a class instead of a struct. A class is a reference type: the list would contain references, and changes to the *objects* that those references refer to would be visible via the references later.
- Keep `vertex` as a struct, but change your code to:

  ```
  vertex v = matrix[j];
  v.visited = false;
  matrix[j] = v;
  ```
- Keep `vertex` a struct, but make it immutable - mutable structs can cause all kinds of issues. Provide a method to create a *new* value from an existing one, but with one particular change. You can then call that method on the result of fetching with the indexer, and set the new value using the setter:

  ```
  matrix[j] = matrix[j].WithVisited(false);
  ```

Personally I suspect the last option is likely to be the best one - a vertex may well be a natural value type. I would *strongly* encourage you to start following .NET naming conventions though - the type should be `Vertex` and `visited` should probably be `Visited`. (The one exception would be if this code is within the `vertex` type, and it's referring to a field. The field should be private, and other code would need to use a property to access the value.)

Comment: Jon, no need to assume OP stated it *vertex is a structure*

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: True, hadn't spotted that. Will remove the first sentence.