# How do i delete an object from ILIST?

Tags: c#, oop

```
class parent

    public string a;
    public string b;
    // child fields
    public string c;
    public string d;
    
    public parent(string a, string b)
    {  
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }


class child1 : parent
    {
     public child1(string a, string b, string c) :base(string a, string b)
    }

class child2 : parent
    {
     public child2(string a, string b, string d) :base(string a, string b)
    }

IList<parent> parent_list = new List<parent>();
parent_list.Add(new child1("243", "ewfwe", "fewf"));
parent_list.Add(new child2("456", "fewf", "efew"));
parent_list.Add(new child1("123", "efe", "ewfew"));
parent_list.Add(new child2("768", "fewf", "ewf"));

var foo = 123
```

I want to delete all data for an object which has 123 as their field a.
I cant seem to find the correct way to execute this. is it possible?

Comment: Please have a look to the documentation first: [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.remove?view=net-5.0) ... Finding items in lists [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16177225/find-element-in-list-that-contains-a-value)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853526/using-linq-to-remove-elements-from-a-listt

Comment: I'm using ILIST though

Comment: How about the count-backwards trick `for(var i = parent_list.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) if(parent_list[i].a == "123") parent_list.Remove(i);`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to modify IList object's members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19408014/unable-to-modify-ilist-objects-members)

Comment: @Jawad I don't think this is a duplicate of the question you linked (which is about modifying items, not the list).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can apply this code.

```
parent_list = parent_list.Where(item => item.a != "123").ToList();
```

More details on [Where](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=net-5.0)

Answer (score 0):

Just count backwards through the list, removing items as you go:

```cs
for(var i = parent_list.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    if(parent_list[i].a == "123")
        parent_list.Remove(i);
```